# Does Visual Studio Online keep a copy of my code if I create a project?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2012, version-control, azure-devops

I would like to use GIT as version control on a Visual Studio 2013 project. It does however require you to create a project with Visual Studio Online. Does this mean that a copy of my code will be stored somewhere, or is the purpose of creating this project only to be allow other users to be added so that you can collaborate?

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have* to use Visual Studio Online to use code control in Visual Studio. You can create the .git and use an external tool (like command line or source safe), or you can use the internal tool.

I think that the Visual Studio community edition struggles to create a git repo without being bound to the Visual Studio Online, but once its created, it works fine with various http remotes (I have a project here which uses two remotes, one being VSO and one being our gitlab repo that we use).

Storing your code remotely (but secured) on one of the major sites can be a major benefit to you in the long run. It gets you into good habits of committing and pushing your source, even when you're working alone.

Answer (score 0):

VSO is basically a cloud-based version of TFS - Microsoft's source control, build and task management system.

In order to use the system for source control purposes, you need to use the "Check In" functionality on the Solution in the VSO project before the cloud-based version is updated. The initial project in VSO will likely be empty.

You can use VSO for collaboration but you don't have to.